# How to fix "element not interactable" (selenium py)

Tags: python, html, web

I get an error when my bot is trying to clear the input.

```
#import codes
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:

        #search input
        code_input = checker.find_element_by_id('input')
        code_input.send_keys(line)
        checker.find_element_by_class_name('button').click()
        code_input.clear()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Checker\script.py", line 52, in 
>       checker.find_element_by_class_name('a-button-inner').click()
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
>       self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
>
> (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.87)

Comment: error shows problem with `click()`, not `clear()`

Comment: element may have class "button" but it may not be real button which you can click. It may need JavaScript code to click. OR there is more objects with class button and you get wrong one.